# Filter ext files in object using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am filtering a file by uploading it. File which I am uploading is in form of object

- And object look like this

```
console.log(files);

{ file-1:
 [{ name: `test.jpg`,
    path: `home/work/test.jpg`,
    size: 456 } ]
  file-2:
 [{ name: `random.jpg`,
    path: `home/work/random.jpg`,
    size: 456 } ] }
```

so i tried to do like this

```
if(files.endsWith(".jpg"){
 console.log("yes");
}else{
 console.log("no");
}
```

Here I am getting this error  `uncaughtException: files.endsWith is not a function`

- Even I tried this too

```
if(files.name.endsWith(".jpg"){
 console.log("yes");
}else{
 console.log("no");
}
```

Here I am getting this error `uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined`

Comment: So many, so many questions and problems could be avoided simply by using Typescript instead of Javascript. Typescript would immediately complain that `file` is an Object, not a string, and therefore has no `.endsWith` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jpgFiles = [];

Object.keys(files).map(key => {
files[key].filter(file => {
    if (file.name.endsWith('.jpg')) {
        console.log('yes');
jpgFiles.push(file);
        return true;
    }else {
        console.log('no');
        return false;
        }})
});
```

Comment: ...or simply `.filter(file => file.name.contains('.jpg'))`

Comment: `var jpgFiles = files.filter(file => file.name.contains('.jpg'))` like this ?

Comment: @LovleshPokra i have changed my output please have a look

Comment: @Vikas I've changed the output. but you need to put some efforts to correct your answer based on the data.

Comment: yes i got my point but array name is getting changed if i am selecting multiple files like `file-1` `file-2`

Comment: it was throwing an error so i replaced `contains` with `endsWith` its working now fine

Answer (score 0):

`files` is an object. [`endsWith` is a string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).

You need to access the `file` array and check the name property either by using the index:

```
files['file-1'][0].name.endsWith('jpg');
```

or, if there's more than one file in the array using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the names:

```
files['file-1'].every(f => f.namee.endsWith('jpg'));

files['file-1'].some(f => f.name.endsWith('jpg'));
```

If you want to check the values across multiple properties you can iterate over them:

```js
const files = {
  'file-1': [{
    name: `test.jpg`,
    path: `home/work/test.jpg`,
    size: 456
  }],
  'file-2': [{
    name: `random.jpg`,
    path: `home/work/random.jpg`,
    size: 456
  }]
}

const result = Object.values(files).every(arr => {
  return arr[0].name.endsWith('jpg');
});

console.log(result);
```

Note, your output is still invalid.

Comment: what is `file[0]` in `files.file[0].name.endsWith('jpg');`?

Comment: It looks at the first element of the array and checks the name of the object.

Comment: i have changed my output please have a look

Comment: You need quotes around `file-1` otherwise it's invalid, You can then use `files['file-1'][0].name`

Comment: there is one problem if i am selecting multiple files `file-1` `file-2`, `file-3` its coming like this